# Draw real time fog of war in 2d game

Tags: xna, 2d, line-of-sight

I have game situation as shown in picture:

[image]

- Red dot: player
- Brown dot: obstacle ( rock, tree, etc)
- Grey: non visible area ( under fog of war)

My question is: how can I draw that kind of shape, changed dynamically, with XNA 4.0. I can calculate each point of this shadow polygon. I would avoid drawing it pixel by pixel due to performance reasons, maybe particles? But i won't have sharp edges with this technique. Any tips?

Comment: The technique is the same as rendering shadows (many resources online). The difference is that instead of rendering the gray area as a shadow, you're using it as a mask to hide parts of the green area.

Comment: I don't know if it also exists under XNA, but with DirectX (and OpenGL I guess) you can use the *stencil buffer* to achieve exactly that effect.

Comment: @Anko this duplicate close vote leads to a chain of duplicate links, and it ends up in a closed question with no answers.  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Seth You're right. I meant to close them all as a duplicate of [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57132/how-do-i-implement-occluded-lighting-in-a-block-based-2d-game), which I think has the clearest phrasing and a clear (if somewhat incomplete) answer. Byte seems to have closed it as a duplicate of [a much vaguer question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46136/how-to-create-2d-shadows) for some reason. (I've voted to reopen it and added my reasons in the comments there.)

Answer (score 9):

See here for an in-depth tutorial/example of doing it in HLSL (shader) code.:

http://www.catalinzima.com/2010/07/my-technique-for-the-shader-based-dynamic-2d-shadows/

If you want sharp edges remove the final blur step.

Comment: +1 Thats right 2D shadow maps are the coolest solution :)