# How to create 2D shadows

Tags: 2d, javascript, html5, html-canvas, shadows

I'd like to create lights and shadows in a 2D environment, like in the image below:

[image: 2D shadows illustration]

I did several searches but got no results. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/dynamic-2d-shadows/

Comment: The link to the actual article in Luis' linked blog post is dead, but here's a link to the archived article (which, incidentally, seems to be the source of your image): http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/2dsoftshadow/default.html.  Note that this requires GL, which for JavaScript means using WebGL.  You can recreate almost all of that logic on plain 2D canvas if you really want, but it'll take more work, more math, and won't be nearly as efficient.

Comment: One more note: that article is pretty old and I wouldn't claim it's the best way to do things on modern hardware.  If you go with WebGL and are comfortable with shaders and framebuffer objects, you can likely do a lot better.

Comment: That's what I saw and have studied this article and do not really feel comfortable with it, I'm trying to develop my own shadow and I like the results anyway thanks for listening =)

Comment: Take a look at this library: [Illuminated.js](http://blog.greweb.fr/2012/05/illuminated-js-2d-lights-and-shadows-rendering-engine-for-html5-applications/)
( [screen shot](http://blog.greweb.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/illuminatedjs.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bhWnl.jpg) ) it's an work in progress, but just reading the source code you can absorb some information about how they made it.